# How can I change field suffix due to its value

Tags: entities

I have a field which is of type number.

I have a view where this field is shown with its suffix. I want it to change when the value of a field is more than 1.

Is it possible to do something? Maybe some preprocess function or some module?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

[Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) would be worth giving a try. The module pages says -

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define
>   conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views. Conditions
>   include:
>
> Equal To Not Equal To Greater Than Less Than Empty Not Empty Views
>   conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the
>   condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about it, but problem is that in my view I don't show up fields but teaser content. I don't think, that this module would help me at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

One of the option thats possible is to write a view field tpl for that field.

Writing a tpl would give you an option to handle 0, 1 and more than 1 options in one go.